# PHP get a variable's name in foreach loop

Tags: php

i'm making a project in PHP and i have a problem. My problem is that i don't know how to get a variable's name in $_GET foreach loop.
My code looks like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $get) {
   $v_name = //I want to be this variable the $get variable's name
}
```

So example: if someone make a post request like this: http://www.example.com/?**something**=example

In this case i want to get the "something".

Thanks everyone who will help me - Jumpak

Comment: use $_GET['something']

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to print the key of array `$_GET`

You should read basics of [`foreach`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) loop.

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$get) {
              //  ^^^      // You can get the index key from Array 
    //$v_name = //I want to be this variable the $get variable's name
    echo $key;
}
```

Comment: This question should just be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, you've solved my problem. :)

Comment: @NigelRen already vote to close :)

Comment: why vote to close AND answer? /shrug

Comment: OP seems new to site. I think new user don't understand how to it work. I agree there is guide/help but do you really new user will read this carefully?

Comment: @MatoSustak mark tick on my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: So you answer a question you know should be closed, and actually voted to close it yourself, and then ask the op for a tick? I guess all you care about is rep, not the quality of the site.

Comment: I agree OP seems new. I disagree with what you did because of that. Why not post a comment on his question explaining what dupes are, showing him the dupe, helping him understand it? Now you've shown OP "doesn't matter if you ask a dupe, someone will answer". And in doing so you duplicated answers, which is what duplicates are supposed to avoid :/